# Oracle: Trying to split a string using REGEXP_SUBSTR, CONNECT BY LEVEL functions and getting duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, select, regexp-substr, connect-by

I have a table that has a column that holds an html string that may or may not be well formed (tried to use xmltable route and it didn't work) which is why I am trying to use the following sql syntax. I am trying to create a query that uses REGEXP_SUBSTR, LEVEL and CONNECT BY LEVEL based on examples I found online but I am not able to get the results I would expect:

I created an example query below:

```
with qry as (
select 1 as id, '<div>What would you like to do today?<a href="#" data-jump="111">Client Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="112">Customer Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="113">Tecnical Service</a></div>' as html_string from dual
union
select 2 as id, '<div>What would you like to do today?<a href="#" data-jump="111">Client Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="112">Customer Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="113">Tecnical Service</a></div><a href="#" data-jump="114">Other Service</a></div>' as html_string from dual
)
SELECT ID,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, '<a.*?>(.*?).</a>', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) as contents,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, 'data-jump="(.*?)"', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) as data_jump
FROM qry
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(html_string, '<a.*?>(.*?).</a>')
```

By running this query, I would expect 7 rows to come back:

| ID | Contents | Data_Jump |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client Servic | 111 |
| 1 | Customer Servic | 112 |
| 1 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |
| 2 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |
| 2 | Customer Servic | 112 |

Instead its coming back with 22 rows.

| ID | Contents | Data_Jump |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client Servic | 111 |
| 1 | Customer Servic | 112 |
| 1 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |
| 2 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |
| 2 | Customer Servic | 112 |
| 1 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |
| 2 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |
| 2 | Client Servic | 111 |
| 1 | Customer Servic | 112 |
| 1 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |
| 2 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |
| 2 | Customer Servic | 112 |
| 1 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |
| 2 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |

I don't know where the problem is that I am getting duplicates. On the actual production table there are a lot of rows so the query just spins and never returns. I suspect its because a lot of duplicates are being generated. Can anyone tell me how to fix the above query so that I can try to transport it onto my actual query?

Thanks,

Comment: What is your expected output from the sample data used in query?

Comment: I have updated my original post with the output.

Comment: that's not going to work.  The connect by/regexp_count trick is for a single string, not multiple rows of strings.  The CONNECT BY is working on the results of both rows.  You have to process each row separately or create a pipelined function to do the processing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the ID in the connect-by clause; but for this to wotk you also need to include a non-deterministic function call; e.g.:

```
AND PRIOR id = id
AND PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL
```

So

```
with qry as (
select 1 as id, '<div>What would you like to do today?<a href="#" data-jump="111">Client Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="112">Customer Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="113">Tecnical Service</a></div>' as html_string from dual
union
select 2 as id, '<div>What would you like to do today?<a href="#" data-jump="111">Client Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="112">Customer Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="113">Tecnical Service</a></div><a href="#" data-jump="114">Other Service</a></div>' as html_string from dual
)
SELECT ID,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, '<a.*?>(.*?).</a>', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) as contents,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, 'data-jump="(.*?)"', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) as data_jump
FROM qry
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(html_string, '<a.*?>(.*?).</a>')
AND PRIOR id = id
AND PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL
```

| ID | CONTENTS | DATA_JUMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client Servic | 111 |
| 1 | Customer Servic | 112 |
| 1 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Client Servic | 111 |
| 2 | Customer Servic | 112 |
| 2 | Tecnical Servic | 113 |
| 2 | Other Servic | 114 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a6e6b4ad2646ac0c61350ac7ce1ef1a9)

Or you could use recursive subquery factoring instead of a hierarchical query, which is maybe easier to understand:

```
WITH rcte (id, html_string, lvl, contents, data_jump) AS (
  SELECT ID, html_string, 1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, '<a.*?>(.*?).</a>', 1, 1, NULL, 1),
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, 'data-jump="(.*?)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM qry
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, html_string, lvl + 1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, '<a.*?>(.*?).</a>', 1, lvl + 1, NULL, 1),
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, 'data-jump="(.*?)"', 1, lvl + 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM rcte
  WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, '<a.*?>(.*?).</a>', 1, lvl + 1, NULL, 1) IS NOT NULL
  OR REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, 'data-jump="(.*?)"', 1, lvl + 1, NULL, 1) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT id, contents, data_jump
FROM rcte
ORDER BY id, lvl
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=81f8356f5c878883495ce7a962c473eb)

Or even, preserving the last character of the 'contents' by removing the stray `.` from the regex as @Gary_W pointed out:

```
with qry as (
select 1 as id, '<div>What would you like to do today?<a href="#" data-jump="111">Client Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="112">Customer Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="113">Tecnical Service</a></div>' as html_string from dual
union
select 2 as id, '<div>What would you like to do today?<a href="#" data-jump="111">Client Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="112">Customer Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="113">Tecnical Service</a></div><a href="#" data-jump="114">Other Service</a></div>' as html_string from dual
),
rcte (id, html_string, lvl, contents, data_jump) AS (
  SELECT ID, html_string, 1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, '<a.*?>(.*?)</a>', 1, 1, NULL, 1),
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, 'data-jump="(.*?)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM qry
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, html_string, lvl + 1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, '<a.*?>(.*?)</a>', 1, lvl + 1, NULL, 1),
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, 'data-jump="(.*?)"', 1, lvl + 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM rcte
  WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, '<a.*?>(.*?)</a>', 1, lvl + 1, NULL, 1) IS NOT NULL
  OR REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string, 'data-jump="(.*?)"', 1, lvl + 1, NULL, 1) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT id, contents, data_jump
FROM rcte
ORDER BY id, lvl
```

| ID | CONTENTS | DATA_JUMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client Service | 111 |
| 1 | Customer Service | 112 |
| 1 | Tecnical Service | 113 |
| 2 | Client Service | 111 |
| 2 | Customer Service | 112 |
| 2 | Tecnical Service | 113 |
| 2 | Other Service | 114 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f03916a4470737bb7e2c1083b9277b7c)

Comment: That is close, I'd be expecting 3 rows for ID 1 and 4 rows for ID2.

Comment: @CreationSL - sorry, wasn't paying attention... missed out a NOT. I've added a recursive CTE option too.

Comment: Your examples are amazing. I found I have a new issue with my data when using CONNECT BY LEVEL version that I'm wondering if it can be fixed. In my original example, I thought I would always have a "data-jump" element in the <a> tag. It appears the production data doesn't always have that element. So if I have 3 records and the first record is missing the data-jump element, the data-jump values from records 2 and 3 are appearing as they are data-jumps values for records 1 and 2. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @CreationSL - you could [change the regex pattern](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=15be3b1dba86601dabedef21fa548ff5), but you might be chasing edge cases forever. That's one of the problems with trying to parse XML with regular expressions; but your example can't be treated as XML.

Answer (score 0):

Just cross join with a series of integers. Also more portable than `CONNECT BY` ...

```
-- your input, don't use in final query ...
WITH qry AS (
SELECT 1 AS id, '<div>What would you like to do today?<a href="#" data-jump="111">Client Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="112">Customer Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="113">Tecnical Service</a></div>' AS html_string FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 2 AS id, '<div>What would you like to do today?<a href="#" data-jump="111">Client Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="112">Customer Service</a><a href="#" data-jump="113">Tecnical Service</a></div><a href="#" data-jump="114">Other Service</a></div>' AS html_string FROM dual
)
-- end of input; real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
-- need a bunch of consecutive integers ...
i(i) AS (
            SELECT 1 FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 FROM dual
)
SELECT
  id
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string,'(?<=data-jump=")\d+',1,i) AS data_jump
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string,'(?<=\"\>)[^<]+',1,i)      AS content
FROM qry CROSS JOIN i
WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(html_string,'(?<=data-jump=")\d+',1,i) <> ''
ORDER BY id,i;
-- out  id | data_jump |     content      
-- out ----+-----------+------------------
-- out   1 | 111       | Client Service
-- out   1 | 112       | Customer Service
-- out   1 | 113       | Tecnical Service
-- out   2 | 111       | Client Service
-- out   2 | 112       | Customer Service
-- out   2 | 113       | Tecnical Service
-- out   2 | 114       | Other Service
```